# Не получается сравнить строки

Tags: php

Всем привет! У меня такая задача, получить код страны пользователя сравнить его и вернуть результат.

```
// Получаю ip клиента
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function get_country($ip) {
    // получаю код страны
    return file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/country");
}
// Кладу код страны в переменную
$countryCode =  get_country($ip); //

// Пытаюсь сравнить 
if (strcasecmp($countryCode, 'RU') == 0) {
    echo 'Russia';
} else {
    echo 'Not work'; // получаю это
}

echo gettype($countryCode); // возвращает string
var_dump($countryCode); // возвращает NULL

//Классическое сравнение тоже не работает

if ($countryCode == 'RU') {
    echo 'Russia';
}
```

Вопрос в том как сравнить строку которую возвращает сервис?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: казалось бы `var_dump($countryCode)` стоило привести. и почему было просто не сравнить `$code == 'RU'` ?

Comment: `echo var_dump($countryCode); // возвращает NULL` Дополнил вопрос. Вот так просто не вышло сравнить почему то

Comment: ответ же очевиден null != 'RU' не так ли?

Comment: никакого echo для var_dump  не надо. var_dump выводит информацию о переменной и ничего не возврашает. когды вы вперед echo добавляете, то очевидно получите это ничего на выводе. но тем не менее до этого var_dump все равно должен отобразаить сведения о типе переменной и ее значении

Comment: Капец, я что то затупил, спасибо ребят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, поправил все таким образом. На всякий случай преоброзовал еще раз код страны в string и потом просто `$countryCode != 'RU'`

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function get_country($ip) {
    return file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/country");
}

$countryCode =  strval(get_country($ip));

if ($countryCode != 'RU') {
    echo 'Russia';
} else {
    echo 'Not work';
}
```